# VSTO C# Clickable Links in Task Pane

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, vsto

I have a custom task pane for my Excel VSTO addin.  In this task pane I want to display a clickable link (for example "https://stackoverflow.com") to the user which opens the user's browser and navigates to the site when clicked.  When I programmatically put the text into the task pane's RichTextBox the text turns blue as if it is being recognized as a URL, however when the text is clicked on nothing happens.  Is there a property I need to set for the RichTextBox to allow the link to be clicked on?[image]

Comment: It seems like `RichTextBox` is present in both WinForms and WPF (this can be used with ElementHost, if you're not already aware). I suggest altering the tags to match whichever you're using. `vsto` and `excel` are not relevant in this case.

Comment: It's a WinForms project, I will change the tags to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the `LinkClicked` event of the RichTextBox.

```
richTextBox1.LinkClicked += richtextBox1_LinkClicked;

public void richtextBox1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    // Opens the link in the default browser.
    Process.Start(e.LinkText);
}
```