# VSTO Add-in C# Adding Clickable Hyperlinks to Text in Task Pane

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vsto, ms-office

In the image below I have a task pane in Microsoft Excel with a Rich Text Box (RTB) in it.  Within this text box I want to make some of the text into clickable hyperlinks. Now, I know if you put a hyperlink into the RTB you can make it clickable using something like "Process.Start(e.LinkText);" as was answered in one of my previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52784009/vsto-c-sharp-clickable-links-in-task-pane). However i'm not sure how to embed a link into the text so that the user doesn't actually see the hyperlink. For example, I want "google" in the below image to take the user to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) when the user clicks on it. Any tips on how to accomplish this?[image: VSTO Task Pane]

Current code to just put some text in the RTB:

```
 string test_string = "Google";
        

    //Used to set the text in the task pane in real time
            foreach (Control rtbControl in GlobalVars.myUserControl1.Controls)
            {
                if (rtbControl is RichTextBox & rtbControl.Name == "documentResults")
                {
                    rtbControl.Text = test_string;
                } 
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `RichTextBox`, you need to use a proper RTF markup where you can specify colors.

```
string RTFText =
  '{\rtf1 ' +
  '{\colortbl ;\red238\green0\blue0;}' +
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ' +
  '{\b {\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "https://www.example.com/" }}' + 
  '{\fldrslt{\cf1 CLICK_HERE\cf0 }}}} ' +
  'consectetur adipiscing elit.}';
```

You may find the [What is the RTF syntax for a hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850575/what-is-the-rtf-syntax-for-a-hyperlink) and [Inno Setup - How to change the color of the hyperlink in RTF text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251000/inno-setup-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-hyperlink-in-rtf-text) pages helpful.

If you use separate controls you can set up [LinkLabel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel?view=netcore-3.1) color-related properties so it may look like on your screenshot:

- [LinkLabel.ActiveLinkColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel.activelinkcolor?view=netcore-3.1) - sets the color used to display an active link.

```
// Set the color of the links to black, unless the mouse
// is hovering over a link.
linkLabel1.LinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
linkLabel1.ActiveLinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
```

- [LinkLabel.DisabledLinkColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel.disabledlinkcolor?view=netcore-3.1) - sets the color used when displaying a disabled link.
- [LinkLabel.LinkColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkcolor?view=netcore-3.1) - sets the color used when displaying a normal link.
- [LinkLabel.VisitedLinkColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel.visitedlinkcolor?view=netcore-3.1) - sets the color used when displaying a link that has been previously visited.

Comment: Just wanted some clarification because i'm a little lost on this answer.  In the first chunk of code, why / how are you putting multiple characters into ... well, a character.  Should those be strings using " " instead? Also how do you display this using "rtbControl" in my code example above. Using "rtbControl.Text" will display all of the text in "RTFText" instead of the actual formatted text. I tried "rtbControl.Rtf", but the "Rtf" property doesn't exist for "rtbControl".